# file upload wont move after folder created on Windows

Tags: php, windows, file-upload, xampp

i found same case just like me in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376648/php-move-uploaded-file-wont-move-the-file-to-the-hosted-server) . I try to make folder with `mkdir`on PHP and it work, also in MySQL it give me link into file. But, why my file wont move into new folder ?if i remove `md5` from php, it works like normal.
I use XAMPP 5.6.30, and my XAMPP folder not on C: system. Do i make mistake ?
here my code :

```html
<?php
 include('conn.php');
 
 foreach ($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $key => $name){
  
  $newFilename = time() . "_" . $name;
  
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$key], 'upload/'.md5(time()).'/' . $newFilename);
  
        $location = 'upload/'.md5(time()).'/' . $newFilename;
        
  mkdir('upload/'.md5(time()).'/');
        
  mysqli_query($conn,"insert into photo (location) values ('$location')");
 }
 header('location:index.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to move the file before even creating the folder

```
// Here you try to move the file but the directory is not created yet
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$key], 'upload/'.md5(time()).'/' . $newFilename);
$location = 'upload/'.md5(time()).'/' . $newFilename;
// after trying to move the file you create the directory, but the directory should be created first
mkdir('upload/'.md5(time()).'/');
```

Here is a working code (see the order: mkdir first then move_uploaded_file:

```
include('conn.php');
foreach ($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $key => $name){
    $ts = time();
    $crptd = md5($ts);
    $newFilename = $ts . "_" . $name;
    $location = 'upload/'.$crptd.'/' . $newFilename;
    mkdir('upload/'.$crptd.'/');
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$key], 'upload/'.$crptd.'/' . $newFilename);
    mysqli_query($conn,"insert into photo (location) values ('$location')");
}
header('location:index.php');
```

Comment: let me try your code, i will give respond in few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Between those two steps:

```
$location = 'upload/'.md5(time()).'/' . $newFilename;
mkdir('upload/'.md5(time()).'/');
```

time() value is not the same and you are using it as a constant
you need to store it in a var first
Also, I don't think it's usefull to create a new folder for every file you upload

Comment: actualy i just want to avoid my user upload file with same name, plus all link is store on MySQL which mean it will help user to donwload or share. in my project, user just 2 options, delete  or upload new one. This project for my school as intern studen..

Answer (score 0):

First, I would make 1 directory for uploads called uploads

mkdir uploads

then make sure its got write permissions

Then I would use the following

```
include('conn.php');

foreach ($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $key => $name){
    $newfilename = "";
    $ts = time();
    $newfilename = $ts."_".$name;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$key], 'uploads/'.$newfilename);
    mysqli_query($conn,"insert into photo (location) values ('$newfilename');')");
}
header('location:index.php');
```

Unless you have a reason to have all the upload folders be unique, I would think that would just get messy and hard to manage over time.

Comment: i have dirrectory called "upload", i use almost same code like you, delete md5 and then all back to normal. But why i can't move my file into md5 folder name ?
i need to do this because i need to prevent / avoid user upload same name file name. I can use `$ts."_".$newfilename`, but i still dont get it why i can't move it ?

Comment: are you making the directory and making it writeable at the same time?

Comment: i guess yes, i never make php file upload before.

Comment: When you put a file into a directory programmatically you need to make sure the directory has write permissions, meaning you can write ( move the file ) to that directory. where mkdir will create a directory on the fly you need to use the chmod command to change the permissions. I still think you would be fine without making the directories, just make sure the file name is as unique as possible.

Comment: after use `mkdir` i can access new folder, read and write someting in there. This is windows, i dont think it need to use chmod, maybe in Linux yes, i will try on Linux next week after i can upload my file into `md5` folder.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is likely that md5(time()) generates a new result every time.
I would make it a variable and use the variable instead of recalculating it every time